# Superfish drop down menu issue in IE9

Tags: jquery

the multi-level drop down menu using superfish plugin shows correctly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but in IE9 the menu appears vertically instead of horizontally. 
any idea for fixing this problem?

meanwhile I used the code of this example(View Page Source):
[http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/example.htm](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/example.html)l

Comment: you are using css3 and i9 does not support css3, only ie10 support it

Comment: Thank you. but it doesn't seem to use the features of css3. so what is the best solution for making the multi-level drop down menu which is compatible to all browsers with different versions?

Comment: you should javascript for dropdown menu. It works truely on all browser. Here is sample link for js drop down list: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/    http://sixrevisions.com/design-showcase-inspiration/50-examples-of-drop-down-navigation-menus-in-web-designs/

Comment: any other idea? other features of menu related to css are ok in IE9 except for menu appears vertically!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer...I fixed this problem by adding the proper DOCTYPE tag to my jsp page.now menu appears and works correctly.thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I created a drop down menu with css and working ie9 like you want: [**SAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2mc7/2/)

You can change css style what you are want.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
     <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```